# Display Terms Comma separated and Hyperlinked

Tags: slug, terms

I'm trying to display Terms comma separated along with hyperlinking each term with its slug however, the terms are not hyperlinked with the slug. Terms are coming comma separated but the slug isn't getting linked.

Let me know what I'm doing wrong.

Here is the code below:

```
<?php $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID ,'policytype' );


                for($cat_count=0; $cat_count<count($terms); $cat_count++) {

                   ?>
                <a href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/policytype/<?php  echo $term->slug;?>" class="link">
                <?php   echo $terms[$cat_count]->name; 
                if ($cat_count<count($terms)-1){
                        echo ', ';
                    }
                ?>
                </a>
                <?php  }?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The comma separated term link list is available with:

```
the_terms( $post->ID, 'policytype', '', ', ', '' );
```

Check the [dev docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_terms/) for more info on this function.

Comment: So, I do not need to write the loop function? Just use the_terms() function? Thanks.

Comment: yes, don't need foreach with it